# How do I call for my stored data, which are strings, in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, jgrasp

I am trying to get the title to print.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
public class TheMixtape
{
 private String Title; 
 private String Artist;
 private String Genre;
 private int Minutes;
 private int Seconds;
 private int Duration;
 public TheMixtape()
 {
  String Title[]={"BROCCOLI", "Ready Set Go(VLone)", "Chill Bill", "Rara", "Too Much Sauce", "Heathens", "No Heart", "Water", "Wake Up"};
  String Artist[]={"Big Baby D.R.A.M.(Prod. By. J Gramm)", "Lil Uzi Vert", "Rob Stone", "Travis Scott ft(Lil Uzi Vert)", "Future","21 Pilots", "21 Savage", "Ugly God", "Fetty Wap"};
  String Genre[]={"Hip-Hop/Rap", "Trap Anthem", "Smooth Jazz", "Pop Music", "Trap Anthem", "Pop Song", "Rap", "Trap/Rap/Pop", "Pop"};
  //int D[]={ 3:45, 3:42, 2:57, 3:07, 3:38, 3:11, 3:55, 2:19, 3:44};   ignore this
  }
  public String getTitle()
  {
  return Title;
  }



  public static void main(String[]args)
 {
   TheMixtape Info = new TheMixtape();
   System.out.println("   Title     "+"Artist     "+"Genre     "+"Duration");
   for (int k=0;k<10;k++)
{
System.out.print(Info.getTitle());
   }
} 
 }
```

I want to be able to say like

```
Info.getTitle(1)
```

then it will give me the first string in the array called BROCCOLI. 
How do I do that

Comment: Use array indexing, e.g. `System.out.println(Info.Title[0]);` The [0] indexes the first element, broccoli, in your array.

Answer (score 2):

Change getTitle() to

```
  public String getTitle(int index)
  {
     return Title[index];  // the user will have to pass zero-based index
  }
```

**Note**

The arrays should be part of the class.  You declared them in the constructor, at which point they pass out of scope and can't be used.

```
public class TheMixtape{
String Title[]={"BROCCOLI", "Ready Set Go(VLone)", "Chill Bill", "Rara", ...};
String Artist[]={"Big Baby D.R.A.M.(Prod. By. J Gramm)", "Lil Uzi Vert", ...};
String Genre[]={"Hip-Hop/Rap", "Trap Anthem", "Smooth Jazz", "Pop Music"...};

public TheMixtape()
{
}
```

Additionally, Java programming standards generally use the same capitalization rules as methods, e.g.:

```
String title[]={"BROCCOLI", "Ready Set Go(VLone)", ...};
```

Comment: Need to fix the constructor too.

Comment: when i pasted you code in it gave an error                        
    TheMixtape.java:22: error: array required, but String found
     return Title[index - 1];  // if pass 1 then get zero'th index